# Deutsche Bezeichnung für geschlechtsrollennonkonforme Kinder

Tags: single-word-request

1. Wie wird ein "geschlechtsrollennonkonformes Mädchen" im Deutschen bezeichnet (ähnlich dem englischen "Tomboy")?
2. Wie wird als Pendant ein "geschlechtsrollennonkonformer Junge" im Deutschen bezeichnet?
3. Wie wird ein "geschlechtsrollennonkonformes Kind" (geschlechts-unspezifisch) im Deutschen bezeichnet?

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob es statt "Rolle" nicht "Klischee" heißen sollte, aber ich hoffe, die Frage ist auch so verständlich.

Nach einer Bezeichnung für ein "geschlechtsrollennonkonformes Interkind" habe ich nicht gefragt, weil ich gar keine Geschlechtsrolle für Interkinder kenne. Sollte ich mich hier irren, dann gerne auch diese Bezeichnung angeben und auf eine Beschreibung der entsprechenden Rolle hinweisen.

An einer Liste abwertender Schimpfworte habe ich kein Interesse, bitte nur sachliche Ausdrücke, Danke.

Comment: *Als Tomboys (im Deutschen etwa „wildes, lebhaftes Mädchen“, Wildfang)* https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomboy

Comment: Unter den Adjektiven fällt mir, spezieller als einfach _unmädchenhaft_, noch [_burschikos_](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/burschikos) ein (wobei die Beschreibung dort schon etwas kurios ist: "betont ungezwungen, ungeniert in den Äußerungen"...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manchmal ist ein längerer und/oder komplizierterer Ausdruck, der dafür aber präzise das Gemeinte bezeichnet, nicht unangebracht oder sogar notwendig (Fachausdrücke im fachlichen Kontext oder in juristischen Angelegenheiten). Ich habe daher schließlich "geschlechtsrollennonkonforme Kinder" (bzw. geschlechtsrollennonkonformes Mädchen, geschlechtsrollennonkonformer Junge) verwendet.

Answer (score 5):

Wildfang für Mädchen, Schöngeist für Jungen

Comment: Wildfang drückt das schon gut aus. Schöngeist ist ein schönes Wort. Duden.de sagt dazu: "jemand, der sich weniger mit alltäglichen Dingen beschäftigt, sondern in Belletristik, Kunst o. Ä. schwelgt, darin aufgeht". Demnach verhält sich ein schöngeistiger Junge geschlechtsrollenuntypisch, aber gilt das Umgekehrte auch? Beispielsweise würde ich aus "hat kein Interesse an Fußball (aktiv & passiv) sondern an irgendeiner anderen Sportart" würde ich jetzt nicht Schöngeist ableiten, erst recht nicht für kleine Kinder. Verbinde den Begriff eher mit Erwachsenen. +1, aber nicht DIE Antwort.

Comment: Klar kannst du auch einen Jungen hernehmen, der gerne Familie spielt. Aber das ist sehr selten. Geschlechtsrollenuntypisch ist für Jungen jedoch bereits, sehr viel und sehr gern zu lesen, eine Begabung für Sprachen zu haben und schon früh einen feinen Sinn für Kunst und Musik zu besitzen. Solche Jungen sind häufig. Bei Mädchen ist das hingegen sogar die Regel.

Comment: Die "geschlechtsrollenuntypischen" Goethe, Schiller, Mozart und Beethoven also. Aha.

Comment: Wären die keine Schöngeister gewesen, hätten sie mit dieser Energie vermutlich Weimar, Salzburg und Wien niedergebrannt.